# How to write in cells in GoogleSpreadSheet using app Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

and sorry for the stupid question.

I know how to program on VBA for Excel, but I´m having a hard time doing the simplest stuff in Google Spreadsheet and I can´t find any good tutorials on-line.

My question is regarding cells. In VBA to write in a cells I would do:

```
cells(1,1) = 2 //that would write the number 2 in the first row of the first column
```

In VBA I can also assign a cell to a variable, like:

```
dim something as long
something = cells(1,1)
```

How can I apply the same principles in google SpreadSheet?

Thank you very much!

I´ve tried what you guys suggested. And now I have a follow up question.

I`m trying to modify the cells in a specific range. I´ve tried this code:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var board = sheet.getRange(2,2,9,9);
board[0][0].setValue(2);
```

But apparently I can´t use array notation. I´m not sure if .setValeu or .getRange are the problem. But is there a way I can use array notation to chance a cell?

Thanks Again!

Comment: Please google for 'google apps script' and read the tutorials there first. See SpreadsheetApp.

Comment: I know it seems I´m lazy.... but I swear it´s not the case. I´ve done the basic tutorials, but I still can´t get the hang of it... I´m sorry for being such a slow learner...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try following:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var cell = sheet.getRange(1,1);
cell.setValue(2);
```

Comment: When using setValue() (without S) you don't need to define a range with 4 parameters, only the cell coordinates. Please update your answer.thx

Answer (score 7):

It's worthwhile looking at the [docs for getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)).

> getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
>
> Returns the range with the top left cell at the given coordinates with
>   the given number of rows and columns.

You can therefore update multiple cells with an array like this:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, numRows, numColumns).setValues(data);
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```